# I want to access first $(this) from the second level in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to get the data attribute on the second level

```
$('.filter-select').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).data()) // this gives me all data 
        $(this).on('change', function() {
            console.log($(this).data()) // but here gives me only on that i clicked i want it all
        })

    })
```

Comment: What is the “second level”? Have you considered using an [arrow function](/q/34361379/4642212)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `each`, and then trying to attach event listeners to each `.filter-select` element use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach a listener to a parent element so that it captures the change events from all the `.filter-select` elements as they "bubble up" the DOM.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.filter-selector', handleChange);

function handleChange() {
  console.log($(this).data());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-id="1" class="filter-selector">
  <option selected>Choose (id: 1)</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select data-id="2" class="filter-selector">
  <option selected>Choose (id: 2)</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply:

```
$('.filter-select').each(function() {
        const allData = $(this).data();
        $(this).on('change', function() {
            // use allData to access all
        })

    })
```